# 404 Not Found after deploy java web application .war file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, server

I'm wrote a web application in java using Spring framework. Tested it and deployed to remote tomcat server. After deploying I have message `OK - Started application at context path [/proxynator]`. But, if I use links like `http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/` and `http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/proxynator/test` I have `404 – Not Found` and `Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`
In Application I have starter class

```
@SpringBootApplication
  public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
  }
```

and controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/proxynator")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private ProxyRepo proxyRepo;

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepo countryRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/countries")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Country> findCountries() {

      return countryRepo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testMethod() {

      return "HELLO";
    }

}
```

I don't know, why I have this problem, because I setting up my tomcat server right, path to my controller is right and application on server is running.
Any ideas how to solve it?

### UPD

I was changed my controller like:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  private CountryRepo countryRepo;

  @RequestMapping("/countries")
  @ResponseBody
  public List<Country> findCountries() {

      return countryRepo.findAll();
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String testMethod() {

      return "HELLO";
  }

}
```

And now my enter point is `/` that calling `testMethod()`, but it doesn't working too.

Comment: is it working on http://109.206.178.66:8080?

Comment: yes, it working. It's tomcat start page.

Comment: can you see request mapping in the spring boot logs?

Comment: how can I do it?
When I start app in local, I can see logs, and all running good. But when I deploying app on remote server, that all not working and I can't see logs. May be I don't know how to do it.

Comment: in my view 109.206.178.66:8080 should not work as your class level mapping is /proxynator. http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/ should not work as well as you do not have"/" in method level mapping. http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/proxynator/test should work I think.  For logs, you can check the console output on the server where you are running the java application. (or do you have any logging configuration which is redirecting logs to some other location).  you can also try http://109.206.178.66:8080/mappings to see all url mappings (if you are using spring-boot-starter-actuator)

Comment: 109.206.178.66:8080 working, but it's a start page of tomcat.
When I calling 109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/proxynator/test, my app should open, but it not working

Comment: How is the .war named ?

Comment: proxynator.war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I was extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override configure method`

```
@Override
override fun configure(application: SpringApplicationBuilder?): 
SpringApplicationBuilder {
    return super.configure(application)
}
```

and I changed project structure like in official documentation. And now it works good.

### PS

I was rewrite project to Kotlin